# C# Specialize generic interface from inherited interface in derived interface

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, interface

I couldn't think out a better title so I'm gonna try to explain it with an example:

I have two classes. One derives from the other:

```
public class Base { }

public class Derived : Base { }
```

And two interfaces. Again one derives from the other and both implement an enumeration of one of the two classes:

```
public interface BaseEnumeration : IReadOnlyList<Base> { }

public interface DerivedEnumeration : BaseEnumeration, IReadOnlyList<Derived> { }
```

It compiled well (although I had to implement GetEnumerator twice in the DerivedEnumeration), but when I tried to use their functions, the compiler complained about ambiguity between the two interfaces.

I've already tried to make a generic base interface, but then i couldn't cast to the derived interfaces from farther derived interfaces.

So how do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are attempting to solve this wont work in any way.. first let me say, that it's kinda strange you need to collect the `Base` class as well as the `Derived` class inside one single type definition.. but i won't focus onto that part cause it's yours. Whatever.. to enumerate through both `Base` and `Derived` collections you'll need to define them explicitly inside your interfaces like this..

```
public interface IBaseEnumeration {
    IReadOnlyCollection<Base> BaseCollection { get; }
}

 public interface IDerivedEnumeration : IBaseEnumeration {
    IReadOnlyCollection<Derived> DerivedCollection { get; }
}
```

but the fact that `Derived` derives from `Base` would lead to a solution that uses only the first interface `IBaseEnumeration : IReadOnlyCollection<Base>` because `Base` covers both instance types..